# How to include syntax checking in TextMate for MACOS?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, textmate, textmatebundles

I am using the TextMate text editor version 2.0.23 on Mac OS Sierra version 10.12.6
I can't find anything similar to syntax highlighting in Bundles. How can I customize whether it is possible the syntax highlighting when editing a script written using Flask & Python? Specifically, I need the text editor TextMate to suggest when I edit the script which variables, for example, are or are not being used, or which are not declared.

For example, in the following code:

```
"""
Module: app_route_index.py
"""

from pkg_app import app

@app.route('/')
def index():

    from flask import render_template

    return render_template('index.html')
```

After pressing CTRL+SHIFT+V, the following screen is displayed:

[image]

Specifically indicating that one of the following packages be installed PyChecker, PyFlakes, Pylint, pycodestyle or flake8 for more extensive code checking. I have installed flake8, apparently it has no effect yet or is not recognized by TextMate during the syntax check. At the end of the screen, it reads that there are no syntax errors.

What I want is that instead of typing the sequence CRTL+SHIFT+V, the TextMate text editor automatically performs the syntax check as I'm coding.

What needs to be done for this to happen?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @KenWhite- Thank you. I have corrected the wording of the question.